# href target div containter same page

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
     #right
     {
       border:3px solid;
       width:100%;
       height:1000px;
       float:left;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="file:///E|/Practice/Assignment/page3.html" >Click</a>
  <div id="right"> heloo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I Click A link Target Appear New Tab But i Want open div Container On Same Page Any Buddy Help Me....

Comment: If you want to open content of `page3.html` in `div#right` you need to use some additional Javascript AJAX. The most simple for implementing is example seen here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 1):

Use [`target="_self"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)

```
 <a href="file:///E|/Practice/Assignment/page3.html" target="_self">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jquery try using `load()` method of jquery:

```
$("button").click(function(){//click event on button
  $("#right").load("pathto/page3.html");
});
```